# how can we add a python program to a mobile application?

Tags: python, mobile, artificial-intelligence

I have a coded an AI Python program and now I want to implement it in a mobile application. How can I add the python program in the mobile application, and which programming language should I use for the application to implement the python program?

Comment: Hey, when asking question on SO please narrow down your questions. Provide samples of what you have tried what problems you have encountered ideally a MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

since python has no built-in mobile app development capability. But you can use other packages to create some sort of mobile application for this you can use packages like Kivy, PyQt, or even Beeware's Toga library.